# Exception when running mstest.exe: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Utility.LicenseHelper. How to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, command-line, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I recently updated our build server, including Service Pack for Visual Studio 2008. I used to be able to run mstest.exe on the command line and from Cruise Control successfully. After the update however i get this error message:

> C:>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
>
> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command
>   Line Tool Version 9.0.30729.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Utility.LicenseHelper'
>   threw an exception. For switch syntax,
>   type "MSTest /help"

I doesn't matter if I use the switches i normally use in Cruise Control. I still get the same exception.

Does anyone have any clues of how I can get this working again. To me it seems like something is missing or broken just can't make out what...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problems I have had with this server comes from a broken update/installation of .net framework 3.5. ..and possibly some other broken update. I have tried to reinstall it (.net framework) but does not work. The only way may be to reinstall everything...